# Getting row locks in SQL server after upgrading from Spring Boot 1.4 to 2.2 . Has the default isolation level changed?

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

We have recently upgraded a Spring Boot app from 1.4 to 2.2. It's using Spring Data JPA, Eclipselink as the ORM, and Spring Data JPA.

We are now getting record locking issues in SQL Server (row in use) whereas we weren't before.

This could be due do bad coding, but in order to track it down it would be useful to know what has changed in this area between the different releases.

Has the default isolation level changed between releases?

Comment: No it hasn't changed and is still `READ_COMMITTED` like it always has been. Upgrading 4 versions (1.5, 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2) will lead to some nice discoveries and the problem is not only you are upgrading Spring Boot but also all the other libraries. SO basically you are in the dark in what the issue is, could be Spring, Spring Data JPA, the fact that you now have JPA 2.2 or Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks Marten. Yes, we've discovered many things on the way, hopefully this is the last. We did a phased migration from 1.4 to 1.5 to 2 to 2.2 and this has just popped up in 2.x. I'll keep on digging.

Comment: you might want to checkout changes in Hibernate maybe some default settings have changed that or Spring Data JPA (If you are using that).

Comment: Thanks, we aren't using Hibernate (using Eclipselink instead) but are using Spring Data JPA so I'll go through the changelog and upgrade guides for that again.

Comment: The fact that you are using EclipseLink, also means you aren't using parts of the auto configuration (for JPA and auto-config only Hibernate is supported). So you have some manual configuration, due  to newer JPA API's you might also need to upgrade EclipseLink.